# Laravel routing: how to pass parameter to controller (not via URL)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, controller, routes

I have two routes: `A/{param}/C` and `B/{param}/C`. Also I have a controller with method:

```
public function index($param, $param1 = false)
{
    //...
}
```

In case of `A/{param}/C` I pass only one parameter - one specified in URL, and the function uses the default for second one. In case of the second route, I want to pass `true` as second parameter. Since it isn't specified in URL, how to pass it to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, without using $_POST, you won't be able to pass a parameter without be being somewhere in the URI (outside of setting a session variable, which i wouldn't advise)

Another option may be to pass it as a query string parameter.  It will still be in the url, but won't necessarily be caught in the route pattern

**URLs:**

```
A/{param}/C
B/{param}/C?param1=true
```

--
**Controller:**

```
public function index($param)
{

   $param1 = Request::query('param1'); // if not present false, if present, {value}

}
```

--

Alternatively, if you'd like a friendly URL, you can place a question mark after your second parameter, indicating that it may or may not exist.  This will match both of the below URLs

**URL:**

```
A/{param}/C
B/{param}/C/true
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('B/{param}/C/{param1?}', 'YourController@index');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index($param, $param1 = false)
{
   //
}
```

Comment: So I can't pass it in array('as' => '...', 'uses' => 'MyController@index', 'param1' => true) or any other way?

Comment: Not when using the `index` method for both.  You could use `Route::get('A/{param}/C', 'YourController@index');`  where `$param1` is set to `false`, then a second route pointing to a different method `Route::get('B/{param}/C', 'YourController@index2');` where `$param1` is set to true.  To keep your code DRY, you could just have one line of code in `index2` calling `index`, passing in `true` `return $this->index($param, true);`